# can't add a new row to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

i have a table and i want to add a new row to it but it doesn't work
i want to copy the first row of it becuase it is just like a template to the new row, then i want to appent it to the body but for some reason it is not working, even i am not getting any error
here is my code:

```
// getting the body of the table
var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");

// getting the row template
var newRow = document.getElementById("tableRow").cloneNode(true);

// trying to add it
tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
```

Comment: Please add the related HTML.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the issue.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML of the table please? When you say it is not working, does that mean that the elements don't change at all, that nothing is added?

Comment: here is a copy to it

Comment: https://codepen.io/dlvihhgo/pen/MWyLXyv

Comment: @AHaworth when i append it, it is not being added

Comment: Works for me.
Note: change the `clone`d row's `id`!

Comment: Like @ATD's answer below, I'd put the `id` on the `table` element, and work from there.

Comment: Am I missing something or is that codepen already working?

Comment: @Taplar There's no function call, so the code just runs as soon as you load the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an id on the TR tag is probably not a good idea as the cloned row will also have that id and you will end up with a collection of rows with the same id.  You can target the first row using the tbody rows collection:

```js
function cloneRow() {
  let tb = document.getElementById("tablebody");
  let nr = tb.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  tb.appendChild(nr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cloneRow();">Clone Row</button>
<table>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Nice!
Having an `id` on a `tbody` is also not such a great idea.
I'd put the `id` on `<table>`.

Comment: you might have a template object that has an `id`, in which case you would want to change the `id` after you clone it before you append it

Comment: @iAmOren - I have found that having an `id` on `tbody` is the best way to do things when you are manipulating rows.  Bear in mind that a table can have multiple `tbody` tags (but only one `thead` and `tfoot`).  It also makes it a lot easier if you need to use tbody.innerHTML = "....." to completely replace all rows.  Also, note that, if you don't specify a `tbody` tag in your HTML, the browser is likely to include one anyway.  In other words, adding a `tbody` tag to your HTML with an `id` allows you to target things more easily.